# Trying to use semget() to get a semaphore set but I keep getting an EEXIST error, even after I make a new key

Tags: c, linux, server, client, ipc

So I'm currently writing a server/client program that will take in three commands (HI, PID and GOODBYE) and process them accordingly. I seem to have run into some trouble with my use of semget() in my server.c code.

The error that I'm getting is "EEXIST", which according to the man pages, says that the key already exists (duh lol) - the thing is, I keep manually changing the key each time and it still gives me the error. Am I not understanding something here? It also seems to work fine for the client.c code. Do any of you guys have an idea as to why I'm experiencing this?

Sorry for the somewhat sloppy code, I've been smashing my head on my keyboard all night over this, I'll do my best to comment out my thought processes. Let me know if there's anything I can do to make it easier to read.

client.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "sys/shm.h"
#include "sys/ipc.h"
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "sys/sem.h"
#include "signal.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <unistd.h>

#define MEM_KEY 99 // memory key
#define SEM_KEY 1337 // semaphore key
#define SEG_SIZE ( (size_t)100 ) // segment size
#define oops( m, x ) { perror(m); exit(x); } // for error checking
int seg_id, semset_id;
union semun{ int val; struct semid_ds* buf; ushort* array; }; // for wait and release functions
void wait_and_lock( int );
void release_lock( int );

int main()
{
    char c;
    key_t memKey = MEM_KEY, semKey = SEM_KEY; // not sure if this is necessary
    char *memPtr;

    if ((seg_id = shmget(memKey, SEG_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0777)) < 0) // get segment ID
        oops("shmget", 1);

    if ((memPtr = shmat(seg_id, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) // attach the memory segment
        oops("shmat", 2);

    semset_id = semget(semKey, 2, ( 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL )); // for some reason I couldn't include this in an if-statement
    // but it seems to work here in the server code
    if (semset_id == -1)
        oops("semset", 2.5);

    wait_and_lock( semset_id ); // this function was something our teacher went over with us.
    // I'm still a little confused with what it's doing.
    while(1)
    {
        printf("enter: "); // get the commands, is there a better way of doing this?
        scanf("%s", memPtr);
    }

    release_lock( semset_id ); 

    while (*memPtr != '*') // not sure if this is necessary, left over from old code that I was experimenting with.
        sleep(1);

    shmdt( memPtr ); // detach the memory

    exit(0);
}

void wait_and_lock( int semset_id )
{
    union semun sem_info;                     // some properties
    struct sembuf actions[2];                 // action set, an array

    actions[0].sem_num = 1;                   // sem[1] is n_writers
    actions[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;            // auto cleanup
    actions[0].sem_op = 0;                    // wait for 0
    actions[1].sem_num = 0;                   // sem[0] is n_readers
    actions[1].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;            // auto cleanup
    actions[1].sem_op = 1;                    // incr n_readers

    if ( semop( semset_id, actions, 2 ) == -1 )
        oops( "semop: locking", 10 );
}

void release_lock( int semset_id )
{
    union semun sem_info;                     // some properties
    struct sembuf actions[1];                 // action set

    actions[0].sem_num = 0;                   // sem[0] is n_readers
    actions[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;            // auto cleanup
    actions[0].sem_op = -1;                   // decr reader country

    if ( semop( semset_id, actions, 1 ) == -1 )
        oops( "semop: unlocking", 10 );
}
```

server.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "sys/shm.h"
#include "sys/ipc.h"
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "sys/sem.h"
#include "signal.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <unistd.h>

#define MEM_KEY 99
#define SEM_KEY 1337
#define SEG_SIZE ( (size_t)100 )
#define oops( m, x ) { perror(m); exit(x); }

union semun { int val; struct semid_ds* buf; unsigned short* array; };
int seg_id, semset_id;
void cleanup( int );
void set_sem_value( int, int, int );
void wait_and_lock( int );
void release_lock( int );

int main()
{
    int id = 0;
    char *memPtr;
    key_t memKey = MEM_KEY, semKey = SEM_KEY;

    signal( SIGINT, cleanup ); // to handle Ctrl-C

    seg_id = shmget( memKey, SEG_SIZE, 0777 ); // get segment ID
    if( seg_id == -1 )
        oops( "shmget", 1 );

    if ((memPtr = shmat(seg_id, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) // attach to memPtr
        oops("shmat",2);

    semset_id = semget( semKey, 2, ( 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL ) ); 
    // this is where there seems to be an issue? This is where the code stops.
    if ( semset_id == -1 )
        oops( "semget", 3 );

    set_sem_value( semset_id, 0, 0 ); // set counters
    set_sem_value( semset_id, 1, 0 ); // both to zero

//Now read what the client put in the memory (still not sure if this works
//because the program hasn't technically gotten that far. So this while loop is more
//of a prototype).
    while(1)
    {
        wait_and_lock( semset_id );

        printf( "\tshm_ts2 update memory\n" ); // will be removed at the end
        sleep(1);
        if(strcmp(memPtr, "HI")==0) // look for HI
        {
            printf("Greetings!\n"); // print this to the server screen
            fflush(stdout);
            memPtr[0] = '\0';

        }
        else if(strcmp(memPtr, "PID")==0) // look for PID and get server's PID
        {
            id = (int)getpid();
            printf("Server pid: %i\n", id);
            fflush(stdout);
            memPtr[0] = '\0';

        }
        else if(strcmp(memPtr, "QUIT")==0){ // check for quit
            shmctl(seg_id, IPC_RMID, NULL); // mark seg to be destroyed
            shmdt(memPtr); // detach segment
            printf("GOODBYE!\n");
            exit(0);      
        }
        release_lock( semset_id );
        printf( "\tshm_ts2 released lock\n" ); // will be removed at the end
    }

    *memPtr = '*'; // still not sure if this is necessary, from old code
    cleanup(0);
    return 0;

}

void cleanup( int n )
{
    shmctl( seg_id, IPC_RMID, NULL );
    semctl( semset_id, 0, IPC_RMID, NULL ); 
}


void set_sem_value( int semset_id, int semnum, int val )
{
    union semun initval;

    initval.val = val;

    if ( semctl( semset_id, semnum, SETVAL, initval ) == -1 )
        oops( "semctl", 4 );
}


void wait_and_lock( int semset_id )
{
    struct sembuf actions[2];                 // action set, an array

    actions[0].sem_num = 0;                   // sem[0] is n_readers
    actions[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;            // auto cleanup
    actions[0].sem_op = 0;                    // wait til no readers
    actions[1].sem_num = 1;                   // sem[1] is n_writers
    actions[1].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;            // auto cleanup
    actions[1].sem_op = 1;                    // increment number of writers

    if ( semop( semset_id, actions, 2 ) == -1 )
        oops("semop: locking", 10 );
}

// Thing 4:  build and execute a 1-element action set: decrement num_writers
void release_lock( int semset_id )
{
    struct sembuf actions[1];                 // action set, an array
    actions[0].sem_num = 1;                   // sem[0] is n_writers
    actions[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;            // auto cleanup
    actions[0].sem_op = -1;                   // decrement number of writer count

    if ( semop( semset_id, actions, 1 ) == -1 )
        oops( "semop: unlocking", 10 );
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: So whats the issue here? is it not minimal? I feel like removing anything could make it hard to spot the problem? I guess I could take out the client.c since the server is having the most problems? Just linking that page doesn't help me at all. @PasserBy

Comment: ou might want to re-read the man page on `shmctl()` and read the man page on `shmdt()`

Comment: For starters, you have a loop that you marked that you will never reach. This is not relevant to your problem. Try and distill the problem to the absolute minimal that is required to fully replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a system V IPC key using the ftok function. Than, that key should be passed as the first parameter to the shmget system call. The same applies to semaphores. Make a System V IPC key using ftok and pass it as the first parameter to semget.